# How can I solve focus out input animation covering svg icon problem?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

When focusing in search input search input is growing left and not covering on the svg icon. But focusing out input is shrinking to the right to be covering the svg icon. I want to the same animation as focusing in (to be reversed) without covering the svg icon. I can start background-color animation to earlier. But I don't want to solve this problem to changing background-color animation time. How can I solve it?

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;
  background: #6f42c1;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #6f42c1 35%, #6610f2 75%, #007bff 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin-top:5rem;
}

.search-3 {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 0;
}
.search-3__text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1) 0s, background-color 0.2s ease-out 0.4s;
}
.search-3__text::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: color 0s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.search-3__text:focus {
  width: 50rem;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: text;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1) 0.2s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.search-3__text:focus::placeholder {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.search-3__icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search-3__icon svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  color: #000;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 1px #7A8288);
}
```

```html
<head>  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700|Roboto:400,400i,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 26 28">
        <title>search</title>
        <path d="M18 13c0-3.859-3.141-7-7-7s-7 3.141-7 7 3.141 7 7 7 7-3.141 7-7zM26 26c0 1.094-0.906 2-2 2-0.531 0-1.047-0.219-1.406-0.594l-5.359-5.344c-1.828 1.266-4.016 1.937-6.234 1.937-6.078 0-11-4.922-11-11s4.922-11 11-11 11 4.922 11 11c0 2.219-0.672 4.406-1.937 6.234l5.359 5.359c0.359 0.359 0.578 0.875 0.578 1.406z">
        </path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <div class="wrap">
    <form class="search-3" action="" autocomplete="on">
      <input class="search-3__text" id="search-3" name="search-3" type="text" placeholder="Sitede ara.." page_search onfocusout="if(this.value !=''){this.value='';}">
      <span class="search-3__icon">
        <svg>
          <use xlink:href="#icon-search" />
         </svg>
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method.

Don't rely on changing `z-index` while animating the text input. 
Instead, set the icon to `pointer-events: none` so that the clicks pass through it to the text box underneath.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;
  background: #6f42c1;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #6f42c1 35%, #6610f2 75%, #007bff 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin-top:5rem;
}

.search-3 {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 0;
}
.search-3__text {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1) 0s, background-color 0.2s ease-out 0.4s;
}
.search-3__text::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  transition: color 0s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.search-3__text:focus {
  width: 50rem;
  cursor: text;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1) 0.2s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.search-3__text:focus::placeholder {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.search-3__icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.search-3__icon svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  color: #000;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 1px #7A8288);
}
```

```html
<head>  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700|Roboto:400,400i,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 26 28">
        <title>search</title>
        <path d="M18 13c0-3.859-3.141-7-7-7s-7 3.141-7 7 3.141 7 7 7 7-3.141 7-7zM26 26c0 1.094-0.906 2-2 2-0.531 0-1.047-0.219-1.406-0.594l-5.359-5.344c-1.828 1.266-4.016 1.937-6.234 1.937-6.078 0-11-4.922-11-11s4.922-11 11-11 11 4.922 11 11c0 2.219-0.672 4.406-1.937 6.234l5.359 5.359c0.359 0.359 0.578 0.875 0.578 1.406z">
        </path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <div class="wrap">
    <form class="search-3" action="" autocomplete="on">
      <input class="search-3__text" id="search-3" name="search-3" type="text" placeholder="Sitede ara.." page_search onfocusout="if(this.value !=''){this.value='';}">
      <span class="search-3__icon">
        <svg>
          <use xlink:href="#icon-search" />
         </svg>
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That is the answer. Thanks a lot.